# Search and paging, but when searching it still dysplay the wrong total of pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Hi I'm using this guide [here](http://afana.me/post/paging-sorting-and-searching-ef-cf-and-mvc.aspx) and i follow it. But I only use search and paging.

When I search for something it still display 16 pages, but it should be like 3 pages.

Here's the code of the controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int page = 1,string search = null)
    {
        IEnumerable<Produkter> produkt = db.Produkter.Where(p => search == null
            || p.Kategorie.Contains(search)
            || p.Material.Contains(search)
            || p.Namn.Contains(search)
            || p.Storlek.Contains(search)
            || p.Tillbehör.Contains(search)
            || p.Tillbehörstyp.Contains(search)
            || p.Benämning.Contains(search)
            || p.Färg.Contains(search));

        ViewBag.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)db.Produkter.Count() / pageSize);
        produkt = produkt.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

        ViewBag.CurrentPage = page;
        ViewBag.PageSize = pageSize;

        ViewBag.Search = search;
        return View(produkt);
```

And here is the view:

```
 @model IList<Mvctest.Models.Produkter>
 @helper biuldLinks(int start, int end, string innerContent)
 {
  for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
  {
    <a class="@(i == ViewBag.CurrentPage ? "current" : "")" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Produkter", new { Search = ViewBag.Search , page = i})">@(innerContent ?? i.ToString())</a> 
  }
 }
 @helper pageLinks()
 {
   exakly the same code on the giude
 }

<div class="product-search">
<form action="@Url.Action("Index", "Produkter")" method="get">
Search <input id="search" name="search" type="text" value="@ViewBag.Search" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

Page:
@pageLinks()
```

Paging is working and searching is working. The problem is when I search the paging still diplay the total of pages. Like 16 pages when all produkt is listed, but it sould be like only 3 pages when I search.

Answer (score 0):

when you do the count you do not count the filtered list

```
ViewBag.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)db.Produkter.Count() / pageSize);
```

try replacing with

```
ViewBag.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)produkt.Count / pageSize);
```

Comment: thx. hi i got one more question.                                                 || p.Benämning.Contains(search)
|| p.Färg.Contains(search)|| p.price.ToString().Contains(search)); but price in database is money value. but i con convert it. it say that ViewBag.TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)produkt.Count() is not a same type. :(

Comment: Should work. I don't have a VS2010 at hand now, but maybe my mistake is that you have to remove the `()` only produkt.Count